# PHP Sigep WEB - Gerar XML da PLP

Tags: php, xml, api

I am implementing on my system a posting system that uses the post office API using the SIGEP WEB

I took as a base the project already started in GitHub https://github.com/stavarengo/php-sigep

I'm having trouble generating the XML from a PLP for validation

```
      require_once 'php-sigep/src/PhpSigep/Bootstrap.php';

      $accessDataParaAmbienteDeHomologacao = new \PhpSigep\Model\AccessDataHomologacao();

      $config = new \PhpSigep\Config();
      $config->setAccessData($accessDataParaAmbienteDeHomologacao);
      $config->setEnv(\PhpSigep\Config::ENV_PRODUCTION);
      $config->setCacheOptions(array('storageOptions' => array('enabled' => false,'ttl' => 10,'cacheDir' => sys_get_temp_dir(),)));

      \PhpSigep\Bootstrap::start($config);

      $accessData = new \PhpSigep\Model\AccessDataHomologacao();
      $phpSigep = new PhpSigep\Services\SoapClient\Real();
      //$response = $phpSigep->SolicitaXmlPlp($plp_number);
      $response = $phpSigep->SolicitaXmlPlp(163779926);

      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($response);
```

The code works fine, I have no problems with code implementation
this is just one of several functions implemented
the problem is the answer I'm having

I always have the answer:

```
PhpSigep\Services\Result Object
(
    [isSoapFault:protected] => 1
    [errorCode:protected] => 0
    [errorMsg:protected] => Resposta do Correios: Plp ainda não atualizada pelo Sara.
    [result:protected] => 
    [soapFault:protected] => 
    [_failIfAtributeNotExiste:protected] => 1
)
```

It looks like I can not generate the XML from the PLP I just generated and close as long as I do not post the order, however I need the XML to take in the postmasters for validation

how to proceed through it?
Has anyone ever had anything like this?

Comment: Questions should be asked in English on this site please

Comment: language correction made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seans like you are using the Post Office's API in 'stage' mode, which have some limitations.

To get more information about how to use it in production, take a look at the official PHP-Sigep repository, here: https://github.com/stavarengo/php-sigep